# Multiple Cloud instances running webservers: How do i sync vhosts config between them?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-2.4

I have an application which i need to move to the cloud and run it on multiple cloud server instances. When a user registers with my application, he gets a (sub-)domain that he can fill with his content. For example, if user1 registers, he gets an URL like user1.mydomain.com. Internally my app creates a new vhost file and reloads apache. If the user decides he wants to pay for my service, than he can also use his own domain name. So he changes the DNS of his domain to my server and my application changes the ServerName in the corresponding vhost and reloads apache. The user can then use his own domain like www.user1.com.

This works like a charm right now. But now i have to move the application to the cloud, where there are at least 3 cloud servers running behind a load balancer.

So if a new user registers, how can i sync the vhost config file between all these webservers? I thought about rsyncing the /etc/apache2/sites-available directory, but how could the other apache servers all be reloaded?

Is there a better solution? The most important thing is that apache should not be restarted, only reloaded.

Comment: How did you do it before? You could keep your config files on the AWS Elastic File System http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/whatisefs.html

Comment: Yes, but the Apache servers need to know if the config has changed, so they need to reload the config.

Comment: You have't answered the question in my comment.

Comment: My application creates the config files and then executes the shell command `service apache2 reload`. This works fine, when all is on the same server, but behind a load balancer one cannot forsee on which instance the scipt is running, so it would only reload the config in one instance and not all.

Comment: Use SNS/SQS to trigger an Apache restart. You'll need a listener on each box https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/queues-and-notifications-now-best-friends/  . The whole setup isn't very elegant. I wonder if you could change your application so Apache listens to every subdomain and you do things in your app layer based on business logic.

Comment: Thanks, that would probably work. I don't know if i could make apache listen to every vhost, because only free users use subdomains. With them, this might work, but paid users have all different domains.

Comment: Maybe Apache could attach to the IP and listen to every request, regardless of domain. It would just pass it on to your application would could return error codes as appropriate. That could be very resource intensive though.

Comment: Maybe this new Service would do exactly what i need? https://aws.amazon.com/de/opsworks/chefautomate/